# Error while retrieving data from database view using code first

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a view in my SQL database. All I want is to retrieve data from that view.

I have added POCO class.

```
namespace WFPersistence.DataModel
{
     public class Instance
     {
         public Guid InstanceId { get; set; }
         public DateTime? PendingTimer { get; set; }
         public DateTime? CreationTime { get; set; }
         public DateTime? LastUpdatedTime { get; set; }
         public int? ServiceDeploymentId { get; set; }
         public string SuspensionExceptionName { get; set; }
         public string SuspensionReason { get; set; }
         public string ActiveBookmarks { get; set; }
         public string CurrentMachine { get; set; }
         public string LastMachine { get; set; }
         public string ExecutionStatus { get; set; }
         public bool? IsInitialized { get; set; }
         public bool? IsSuspended { get; set; }
         public bool? IsCompleted { get; set; }
         public byte? EncodingOption { get; set; }
         public byte[] ReadWritePrimitiveDataProperties { get; set; }
         public byte[] WriteOnlyPrimitiveDataProperties { get; set; }
         public byte[] ReadWriteComplexDataProperties { get; set; }
         public byte[] WriteOnlyComplexDataProperties { get; set; }
         public string IdentityName { get; set; }
         public string IdentityPackage { get; set; }
         public long? Build { get; set; }
         public long? Major { get; set; }
         public long? Minor { get; set; }
         public long? Revision { get; set; }
     }

     public class Instances : Collection<Instance>
     {
     }
}
```

This is how I am trying to map with view.

```
 public class WFPersistenceStore : DbContext
 {
     public WFPersistenceStore() : base("WFPersist")
     {
     }

     public DbSet<Instance> PersistedInstances { get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         modelBuilder.Entity<Instance>().ToTable("System.Activities.DurableInstancing.Instances");
     }
 }
```

This is how I am connecting with view

```
using (var PersistStore = new WFPersistenceStore())
{
    var result = from t in PersistStore.PersistedInstances
                 select t;
    ////
    ///
}
```

I am getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   RentalHost.exe
>
> Additional information: The database name
>   'System.Activities.DurableInstancing.Instances' is invalid. Database
>   names must be of the form [.].

Comment: Your table name needs to be in the form [schema].[object_name] - try renaming it.

Comment: I tried in that way but then it complains model does not match and need to update. Becuase in that case it match my POCO class with actual table scheme and not with view scheme. Hope you understood what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by just putting the following line inside the constructor of my context class (i.e. WFPersistenceStore).

```
Database.SetInitializer<WFPersistenceStore>(null);
```

This wasn't mentioned anywhere clearly in official documents if i am not wrong.

The above line needed for `EF6` version only but not required for earlier versions of EF.

Answer (score 0):

Your method should be like

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Instance>().ToTable("Instances");
        }
```

Comment: Even this way it gives same error "The model backing the 'WFPersistenceStore' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)."